# Can't find variable: require

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I use Angular with gulp. When i do a "gulp test", i got the error "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require in /bower_components/gulp-ng-config/gulp-ng-config.js:3

gulp/config.js

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path'),
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    conf = require('./conf'),
    gulpNgConfig = require('gulp-ng-config');

gulp.task('config', function () {
  gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/config.json'))
    .pipe(gulpNgConfig('EnvConf', {
      environment: 'local'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/')));
});

gulp.task('config:build', function () {
  gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/config.json'))
    .pipe(gulpNgConfig('EnvConf', {
      environment: 'production'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/')));
 });
```

gulp/server.js

```
gulp.task('serve', ['config','watch'], function() {
   browserSyncInit([path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve'), conf.paths.src]);
});

gulp.task('serve:dist', ['config:build','build'], function() {
  browserSyncInit(conf.paths.dist);
});

gulp.task('serve:e2e', ['config','inject'], function() {
  browserSyncInit([conf.paths.tmp + '/serve', conf.paths.src], []);
});

gulp.task('serve:e2e-dist', ['config:build','build'], function() {
  browserSyncInit(conf.paths.dist, []);
});
```

I try node v6.1.0 and v5.10.1.

Comment: Did you install [node](https://nodejs.org/en/)?

Comment: node --version
    v5.10.1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have installed `gulp-ng-conig` as a *bower* dependency.

This is a gulp plugin, which is a **node dependency**.

Try installing with `npm install gulp-ng-config --save`